# Update menu item in Glassware timeline

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I need to update menu item display name after taping that.I get Timeline item notification and change menu item then change its Display name property and then update time line.but same Menu item there.

```
 var menuItem = item.MenuItems.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Payload.Equals("ONSITE"));
                if (menuItem != null)
                    {
                    var menuValue = menuItem.Values.FirstOrDefault(v => v.State.Equals("DEFAULT"));
                        if (menuValue != null)
                            menuValue.DisplayName = "Confirmed";
                    }
                    service.Timeline.Update(item,item.Id).Execute();
                }
```

is this possible? or any method to update menu item data.

Comment: Have you seen `menuItems[].values[].state` in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert)? It will let you define custom text and icons for different states such as the pending state and the confirmed state.